# Islower function glitch

Tags: c, function, lowercase, caesar-cipher, cs50

I'm doing the CS50x class and I am stuck at a glitch. I asked them what was going on and no one knew what was going on.

Whenever I try to print a lowercase f it always comes up as ?. Try doing 23 as the argument and `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` as the input. It's messed up. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[]){
  if(argc !=2){
    return 1;
  }

  string x = GetString();
  int key = atoi(argv[1]);

  for(int a = 0, n = strlen(x); a < n; a++){
    char i = key + x[a];

    if(islower(x[a])){
      if(i > 122){
        i = (i-122) + 96;
      }
    }
    if(isupper(x[a])){
      if(i > 90){
          i = (i-90) + 64;
      }
    }
    printf("%c", i);
  }

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's because your `char i` defaults to `signed`.  When you add `23` to a lowercase letter, anything that is above `104` (being `127-23`) is going to wrap around into negatives.  Looking at your code, it will stay negative because it fails the subsequent tests and does not get modified.

It's usually best to do `char` arithmetic with `int`, then convert back to `char`...  But you could probably fix this by using `unsigned char`.

Comment: There's no need to convert back to `char` here at all, since the OP is outputting `i` using the `%c` conversion specifier of `printf()` which takes an `int` as argument.  Simply changing the type of `i` to `int` should fix it.